# Telegram Bot - ошибка с методом send_media_group

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Вот кусок кода

```
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media = [{"type": "photo", "media" : "D:\Folder\Vlad\Картинки\images.jpg"}, {"type": "photo", "media" : "D:\Folder\Картинки\s1200.jpg"}])
```

Создаю бота в телеграмме
С методом send_photo проблем не было
Когда пытаюсь запустить код с этим куском, то такая ошибка:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: there are no messages to send"
```

Comment: Попробуйте загрузить файлы на сервер Telegram, а потом использовать `file_id` вместо имени

Comment: Вот это вот не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0):

Тоже стояла задача отправить группу фото.
Вот как у меня заработало:

```
    bot.send_media_group(
        chat_id=message.from_user.id, 
        media=[types.InputMediaPhoto(i_pic) for i_pic in pics]
    )
```

Comment: Привет, можешь дать свой телеграмм?

Answer (score 0):

Использовал такой метод. Работает

```js
ctx.telegram.sendMediaGroup(message.chat.id, media).then((result) => {
    }).catch((err) => {
    });
```

Comment: Какой-то это не python...